# [Windows Phone]-How to save cookie/session in webclient

Tags: c#, session, cookies, cookiecontainer

I'm trying create a windows phone application, get data from server using an api by webclient. It's have to make 2 steps:

1. Send the first request with public key to verify with server. The response contain message, if "Valid key", the session was created within 15 minutes.

> {"code":200,"content":null,"message":"Valid key"} **or** 
>   {"code":401,"content":null,"message":"Invalid key"}.

1. Next, after receive message "Valid key", going to send the second request to get data.

---

The API working correctly with web browser on PC

> {
>   code: 200,
>   content: null,
>   message: "Valid key"
>   }

```
{
code: 200,
content: {
topics: [
{
absViewUrl: "http://www.depvd.com/view/Chan-Dai-Xu-Han-Xinh-Ghe/TLcfZPtUUe",
absWidgetImage: "http://photo.depvd.com/13/317/08/ph_o1SJotZgie_OIusQYb2_wi.jpg",
commentsCount: 0,
likeCount: 0,
models: [
{
absModelUrl: "http://www.depvd.com/model/Choi-Byeol-Yee/2sj1OYbIsN",
name: "Choi Byeol Yee"
}
],
photos: [
{
absNormal: "http://photo.depvd.com/13/317/08/ph_o1SJotZgie_OIusQYb2_no.jpg"
}
],
title: "Chân dài xứ Hàn xinh ghê",
user: {
absUserUrl: "http://www.depvd.com/user/Takei-Emi/o1SJotZgie",
displayName: "Takei Emi"
},
viewCount: 17
},
```

But when i send the 2nd request using webclient in code, always response message "Access denied"

> 

```
 public void GetAlbum(int page)
        {

            string url = "http://open-api.depvd.com/Topic/GetNewTopics?page=1";
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();            
            webClient.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(AlbumDownloaded);
            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        }
```

> {"code":401,"content":null,"message":"Access denied"}

May be the webclient in windows phone does'nt save the seesion/cookies after the first request.